# Using MouseUp instead of AutoFocus as a solution for iPad or iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, autofocus, mouseup

Here is my script. I'm trying to get the one field to auto focus on all browsers, mobile borwsers, and iPad browser, but I cannot get it to work. Can someone help me please? This is what I'm trying: o

On http://boxoffice.jokerzcomedyclub.com/scanner/ , the object is to get the field to automatically start the cursor in it. It works on computers, but it doesn't work on iPad or iPhone, so I'm looking for other alternatives.  Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Validate Ticket</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.autofocus-min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.label').mouseup(function(){
      $('[autofocus=""]').autofocus();
    });
    /*$('.label').mouseup(function(){ $('input').focus(); });*/
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*  window.onload = function() {
        document.forms[0].barcode.focus();
    }*/
</script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<br />
<div style="width:200px; border:1px #999 solid; text-align:center;">
<form action="" method="get">
<select name="Events" class="listclass">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.label').focus();
});
```